# ConnectManager.Load not found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

'm working on playing a audio file and planning to play two parallel playing of files so chose "SoundEffect" for playing audio file.

[Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx)

```
        SoundEffect back;
        back = ContentManager.Load<SoundEffect>("/Sounds/Background/bkm.mp3")
```

'm not getting that Load object.

Getting this error-->

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load(string)'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content loading must occur inside the main Game class' `LoadContent()` method. Put your second line in there and try to run it.

Also your path to the file contains errors. It must look either like this:

`"\\Sounds\\Background\\bkm"`

or like this:

`@"\Sounds\Background\bkm"`.

Don't include file extension and use `\` backslash in paths for content manager.

Also it's a great idea to run this check first if you stumble upon `File not found` exception:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("\\Sounds\\Background\\bkm.mp3"))
{
    // if you can step into this, it means the file exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe:

```
SoundEffect back;
var Cm= new ContentManager();
back = Cm.Load<SoundEffect>(@"/Sounds/Background/bkm.mp3")
```

Comment: The problem is not with the file, but with the instance of content manager.

Comment: This won't help since the ContentManager is not tied to the game in any way. There is no GameServiceContainer in your code or anything, that would require it to work. This code just has to be placed inside the `LoadContent()` of main game class.

Answer (score 0):

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load(string)'

So, create an instance:

```
var contentManager = new ContentManager();
var back = contentManager.Load<SoundEffect>("/Sounds/Background/bkm.mp3");
```

Comment: Guys you're not helping. A new instance of `ContentManager` without `GameServiceContainer` is useless, and that isn't even the problem. If this error occurs, it means that the content loading isn't going on in the right place.